# Using awk to print pairs of records having overlapping range of values between two columns

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have different records corresponding to ranges with start($6) and stop($7).
What I want to do is to print out all pairs of records having overlapping ranges.

For example, my data is as follow:

```
id1 0   376 . scaffold1 5165761 5166916 
id2 0   366 . scaffold1 2297244 2298403 
id3 155 456 . scaffold1 692777  693770 
id4 185 403 . scaffold1 102245  729675
```

What I want is a result like

```
id3 id4
```

because the range of id4 is overlapping with id3.
I have been searching the solutions all over the internet but it seems there is nothing approaching to my problem.

I would really appreciate if some might give some advice.

---

After following the advice of some from the below replies, I did try this code which did work !

`awk '{start[$1]=$6;stop[$1]=$7;} END {for(i in start) {for(j in stop) {if(start[i] >= start[j] && start[i] <= stop[j]) print i,j}}}' file | awk '{if($1!=$2) print}' -`

The processing time was quite short...it was done after not even 1 minute for a file with 1400 records.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Brute-forcing that is actually quite easy. Read the start and stop data into an associative array indexed by the `id` column, then check all possible pairs of ids. Just google overlapping intervals or something like that.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs:  True, but if the number or records is large, the processing time (and the memory) may explode. How many records contains the file?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte around 1500 records...

Comment: wrt the script you posted - rather than printing everything and piping it to a second awk script that then compares 2 values and only prints when different, wouldn't it make sense do just do that comparison in the first script before printing in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    beg[$1] = $6
    end[$1] = $7
    ids[++numIds] = $1
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=numIds; i++) {
        idI = ids[i]
        for (j=1; j<=numIds; j++) {
            idJ = ids[j]
            if (idI != idJ) {
                if ( ( (beg[idI] >= beg[idJ]) && (beg[idI] <= end[idJ]) ) ||
                     ( (end[idI] >= beg[idJ]) && (end[idI] <= end[idJ]) ) ) {
                    if ( !seen[(idI<idJ ? idI FS idJ : idJ FS idI)]++ ) {
                        print idI, idJ
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
id3 id4
```

The input file you provided in your question doesn't cover many cases so given this input file with a lot more overlap variants in it:

```
$ cat file
id1 185 403 . scaffold1 10  20
id2 185 403 . scaffold1 11  19
id3 185 403 . scaffold1  9  10
id4 185 403 . scaffold1 20  21
id5 185 403 . scaffold1  9  11
id6 185 403 . scaffold1 19  21
id7 185 403 . scaffold1 10  20
id8 185 403 . scaffold1  1   8
```

Try the above:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
id1 id3
id1 id4
id1 id5
id1 id6
id1 id7
id2 id1
id2 id5
id2 id6
id2 id7
id3 id5
id3 id7
id4 id6
id4 id7
id5 id7
id6 id7
```

vs the scripts + pipe you provided at the end of your answer:

```
$ awk '{start[$1]=$6;stop[$1]=$7;} END {for(i in start) {for(j in stop) {if(start[i] >= start[j] && start[i] <= stop[j]) print i,j}}}' file | awk '{if($1!=$2) print}' -
id3 id5
id4 id6
id4 id7
id4 id1
id5 id3
id6 id7
id6 id1
id6 id2
id7 id3
id7 id5
id7 id1
id1 id3
id1 id5
id1 id7
id2 id5
id2 id7
id2 id1
```

and notice that your scripts report the overlap between some (but not all) of the ids twice:

```
id1 id7
id7 id1
id3 id5
id5 id3
```

while my script only reports them once courtesy of `!seen[(idI<idJ ? idI FS idJ : idJ FS idI)]++`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion !

Answer (score 2):

This solution requires GNU `awk`:

```
{
    start = $6 * 10 + 5;
    stop = $7 * 10;
    data[start] = data[start] " " $1;
    data[stop] = data[stop] " " $1;
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
    for (d in data) {
        count = split(data[d], fields);
        for (i in fields) {
            id = fields[i];
            if (d % 10 == 5) { # start
                for (s in started) {
                    print s, id;
                }
                started[id] = 1;
            } else { # stop
                delete started[id];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is this: put the start and stop markers (I called them indices, possibly a bad choice) in a single array and sort that array by its indices. Then, iterate through the array. If you encounter a "start" marker, put it in another array (called "started"). If you encounter a "stop" marker, remove it from that array. Now, if you encounter a "start" marker, that interval overlaps with all intervals currently in the array "started", so print out the matches. By making sure that the "stop" markers precede the "start" markers with the same original index, you can eliminate corner cases.

Comment: That reports overlaps where there are none and misses some that do exist. Try it against the sample input file I added to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38484066/1745001).

Comment: They are unique in the sample I mentioned. Oh hang on. By indices you mean the start and stop values, not the actual id value at the start of each line. OK then....

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, that's what I meant. In fact, going the extra mile isn't that difficult.

Comment: Sounds good. I personally can't wrap my head around the logic but it's probably just me and I haven't put a huge amount of time into it...